# Upload images to database

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, database, appharbor

I am new i WPF but i make wpf application which have sql database server. My Database is only 20 mb because it's on "appharbor". In this app every user can upload image for avatar but i can't save this pictures for every user because my db is too small. Can you recommend me where to save these images and how to upload their urls in db so every user can see other users avatar picture.If anyone can give me other ideas how to upload images for every user to database tell please me. Also i don't have money to buy host because i am from Bulgaria and i am student 11-th grade. 
Thank you a lot.

Comment: you could try using gravatar? Not sure how it works but I imagine there is some sort of API you can connect to.

Comment: In my api you can register and have profile. User have image for avatar and information for itself.

Comment: If it's a WPF application, don't store their avatar images in a DB, store it on the local machine. If you need to share the avatars (the app is for something like IM,) let them use a service such as Flickr or Gravatar to either host the image or have the app push the image from the local machine when connecting.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution from my opinion is to make `nvachar(max)` field in your table 
and you have to insert only image `url` on it.

As usual you will take the image path from your `uploader` and then save this path as previous 
Or you can either put the image on your  server or ask the user to put the image `url` instead of make uploading process.